# R packages nlt/adlift/ebayesthresh use huge amounts of memory; how to improve performance?

Tags: performance, optimization, r, memory, parallel-processing

It all started with an **R package** I needed to use badly (**'nlt'**), which has 2 other (quite large) package dependencies (**'adlift'**, **'ebayesthresh'**). I needed it to analyze a data sample of about 4000 points.

The algorithms create many 'hidden' vectors, so even though at first glance you'd think you have enough memory to load the data sample and process it, things turn sour fast. At this point I should mention I have both Ubuntu x64 and Windows x64 at my disposal with 4GB of RAM.

Out of sheer curiosity and masochism I guess, I decided to give it a try on an **Amazon EC2** instance. I ended up trying several of them and I stopped at the **High-Memory Extra Large Instance** 17.1 GB memory with 6.5 ECUs, when again, I ran out of memory and Ubuntu killed my running function.

I ended up using the **split-apply-combine** approach with **'snowall'**, **'foreach'** and **'doSMP'**. I chuncked my data, processed each chunck and combined the results. Thank heavens lapply and sfLapply exist. The sample was analysed in under 7 minutes on my laptop.

I guess I should be happy, but 7 minutes is still a lot and I'd like not to have to jump the gun to Amazon EC2 again, unless there really is no other thing left to shorten run time.

I did some research, the **'bigmemory'** and **'ff'** packages for R seem to allow considerable speed-ups, especially if I use filebacked data.

The **'nlt'** package only takes vectors as input, and **'bigmemory'** for instance has its special data type, the big.matrix. Even if I'd magically be able to feed big.matrixes to the **'nlt'** package, this still leaves the many new vector allocations with standard R functions that are hard-coded into the package and it's dependencies.

I keep thinking of **aspect-oriented programming / monkey-patching** and I managed to find apparently the only R package for such a thing, **'r-connect'**.

Now, as I see it, I have 2 main options:

- manually rewrite the nlt package and all its function dependencies from the other 2 packages and instead of the standard R list(), matrix() and so on, use **'bigmemory'** functions, a nightmare in the making.
- replace the standard R list, matrix etc. with **'bigmemory'** functions

Am I jumping the shark? Can anyone else propose another solution or share similar experiences?

Comment: Perhaps your best approach is to choose software that doesn't make such unrealistic demands on memory.

Comment: I usually do all my work in Python and I'd gladly take other options, if they had packages that provide the same functionality as the one I mentioned. Sadly there are none and the package is huge, so it would be very time consuming for me to just port it into a different language of my choice.

Comment: @jakker: software != language, and 3 contributed packages are not representative of R.  I regularly use base R to manipulate tens of millions of data points with 3GB of RAM on 32-bit Windows, so 4000 points hardly qualifies as "big data".  You can write software in any language that makes unrealistic demands on memory too.

Comment: "You can write software in any language that makes unrealistic demands on memory", it's just easier in R!

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: I hope you understand that those packages are not coded by me. I really don't understand your need of telling me how you regularly manipulate millions of data points with standard R functions, when you haven't even bothered to take a look at how complex the 'nlt' package algorithms are. My 'hardly big data' 4000 points end up being expanded into a much larger dataset. The package comprises a mix of adaptive wavelet lifting techniques, genetic algorithm-type algorithms and heavy math stuff.

Comment: One of the big problems the R community has is its inability to recognise the weaknesses of R. What it needs is a strong group of vocal critics. Oh, and some reference type variables would help too!

Comment: @jakker: I know you didn't code those packages, but you have their source.

Comment: The massive memory usage for 4000 points is very strange. I would take a small sample of the data and see if there was a relationship between memory usage and sample size, or if there was some bug in the software that meant it used essentially infinite memory. 4000 points is not a big data problem (unless its 4000 points each with 90000 values).

Comment: @Spacedman: Thanks for trying to help. The package does a decomposition of the original 4000 points, they end up being expanded into a bunch of coefficients, many, many more points than the original data. I'm currently trying all the optimization tips that have been suggested by everyone who jumped in to help. Thank you again!

Comment: I fixed the title from the OP's vague, not-too-relevant and overly general-sounding original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option would be to profile those 3 packages' memory use and remove any redundant data and remove objects when they're no longer needed.

UPDATE:
`nlt` isn't too complicated; it mostly wraps `adlift` and `EbayesThresh` functions, so I would take a look at those two packages.

Take adlift/R/Amatdual.R for example: `Adual` and `Hdual` are initialized at the beginning of the `Amatdual` function, but they're never indexed in the function; they're completely re-created later.

```
Adual <- matrix(0, n - steps + 1, n - steps + 1)
Hdual <- matrix(0, n - steps, n - steps + 1)
...
    Hdual <- cbind(diag(length(newpoints) - 1), lastcol)
...
Adual <- rbind(Hdual, as.row(Gdual))
```

There's no need for those two initial allocations.

`adlift` and `nlt` also have several uses of `apply` that could be switched to row/col Means/Sums.  I'm not sure how much this would help with memory usage, but it would be faster.  I.e.:

```
apply(foo, 1, sum)   # same as rowSums(foo)
apply(foo, 2, sum)   # same as colSums(foo)
apply(foo, 1, mean)  # same as rowMeans(foo)
apply(foo, 2, mean)  # same as colMeans(foo)
```

Comment: I think I forced garbage collection via AOP at certain points during various functions' execution. I'll try something similar and use rm() as well this time. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @jakker: make sure to run gc() after rm() to free the memory.

Comment: Yep, I think I'm going to dig in and re-write as much as I can. I just re-confirmed myself that it's so slow because of the way memory is allocated. I further decreased the size of my data chunks for the split-apply-combine and I almost halved my run time. Damn this bloody R!! Thanks again for your advice!

Comment: @jakker: The problem here is code that was written by people who have a deep understanding of mathematics and a shallow understanding of computer science---happens all the time in computational science, no matter the language.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: one of the functions in the package ended up storing full previous matrices from all iterations; so in the end it ended up with a list of matrices containing: a 4097x4097 matrix, a 4096x4096 matrix and so on until the beginning. No wonder performance was awful. Replacing apply turned out to improve performance further.

Comment: @jakker: Awesome work tracking down the issue!  Thanks for following up.  The package maintainer would probably appreciate your feedback too.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: He's already been notified, I hope he's happy as well that it's no longer running out of memory. As I was able to find out, this is inherited code, not written from the ground up by him, so it's understandable. Have a lovely day there!